# How to select foreign key value in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I've two tables one is **car_category** having the fields - **id,type**.
Another table named  **vehicle** having field - **c_id**(FK Refers **car** - id).
Now I want to display the FK(c_id) value which is **car**-type.
I've below code in models,

```
class Car extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $table = 'car_category';

    public function vehicles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Vehicle');
    }
}
```

vehicle model,

```
class Vehicle extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $table = 'vehicles';
    public function cars()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Car');
    }
}
```

What 'll be my query for this? I've tried this code, results error.

```
$vehicles = "SELECT cars.cartype,vehicles.model FROM cars,vehicles 
             WHERE cars.id = vehicles.c_id";
```

How can I achieve this? Can anybody help me?

Comment: your class car should be `Car`

Comment: What  about the query Any mistakes?

Comment: I'm confused with your tables, in query you have `cars` and `vehicles` while models have `car_category` and `vehicles`

Comment: `cars` and `vehicles` are function names of relationship models.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
class Car extends Model  
{
protected $guarded = [];
protected $table = 'car_category';

 public function vehicles()
 {
   return $this->hasMany(Vehicle::class, 'c_id');
 }
}
```

The vehicle model

```
 class Vehicle extends Model
 {
  protected $guarded = [];
  protected $table = 'vehicles';

  public function cars()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Car::class, 'c_id');
  }
 }
```

Eloquent determines the foreign key of the relationship based on the model name. In this case, the  Car model is automatically assumed to have a car_id foreign key. If you wish to override this convention, you may pass a second argument to the method

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

To get the Car along with their Vehicle information you can do a query using Eager Loading

```
$result = Car::with('vehicles')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks,But what should be the query?

Comment: To get the Car along with their Vehicle information you can do a query using Eager Loading

$result = Car::with('vehicles')->get();

Comment: Ok and get vehicle table's data using `$result->vehicles->car_type;` Is n't it?

Answer (score 1):

To get the `Car` along with their `Vehicle` information you can do a query using [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

```
$result = Car::with('vehicles')->get();
```

One more correction you have specified class name as string literals without specifying [FQN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name), relationships in models should be defined using fully qualified name

Car Model

```
class Car extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $table = 'car_category';

    public function vehicles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Vehicle::class);
    }
}
```

Vehicle Model

```
class Vehicle extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $table = 'vehicles';
    public function cars()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Car::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Class 'Vehicle' not found` in HasRelationships.php (line 487)

Comment: @saranya I have udpated my answer also if you have used different namespaces for your models not `App\Models`  then i suggest you to put correct namespaces in defining relationships

Comment: Ok.How to get the table data in view blade.By `$result->vehicles->car_type;` Right?

Comment: @saranya yes pass it to view and then loop through your data and then loop through `vehicles` for each car

Comment: When I dd the result it gives only the car table data

Comment: In view displays the error :`Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\movecab\resources\views\vehicles\vehicle.blade.php)`

Answer (score 0):

Change from `class car` to `class Car`

After that you can select with `Car::first()`, the related table data can be found in `Car::first()->vehicles`

You can also add a where() method on models, if you have more than one record, use a foreach()

Comment: Can you give  me a sample example?

Answer (score 0):

```
In Model,
 class Vehicle extends Model
 {
protected $guarded = [];
protected $table = 'vehicles';

 public function cars()
{
 return $this->belongsTo(Car::class, 'c_id');
}
}
```

In controller,

```
    $vehicles = Vehicle::all();
    return view('vehicles.vehicle',['vehicles'=>$vehicles]);
```